# How to fix the runtime crash - QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread?

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I have written a QT - webkit application. this application fires a callback when my pSeudo driver gets the character 'l'. However, the application crashes during a firecallback - it says -  QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread. I don't know to fix this, I tried doing moveToThread, but it doesn't help. Please help me here.

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QWebFrame>
#include <QWebPage>
#include <QWebView>
#include <QThread>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


class DemoThread;

class MyJavaScriptOperations : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
 public: 
 QWebView *view;
 DemoThread *m_pDemoThread;
  MyJavaScriptOperations();
  void firecb();
  bool slot_installed;
 signals:
 void  alert_script_signal();
public slots:
  void JS_ADDED();
  void loadFinished(bool);

private:

};

 class DemoThread : public QThread {
     public:

    DemoThread( MyJavaScriptOperations *pJavascriptOp);
    protected:
        void run();
    private :

    MyJavaScriptOperations *m_pJavascriptOp;
    };

DemoThread::DemoThread(MyJavaScriptOperations *pJavascriptOp):m_pJavascriptOp(pJavascriptOp)
{

}

void DemoThread:: run()
{
  int filedesc = open("/dev/pSeudoDrv", O_RDONLY);
    if(filedesc < 0)
      {
          qDebug()<<"Couldn't open Driver.";  
      }

   unsigned char buff;

  while(1)
  {
    read(filedesc,&buff, 1);

    qDebug()<<"The code received is "<< buff;

    if ( (m_pJavascriptOp->slot_installed == true)  && (buff == 166))
    {
      m_pJavascriptOp->firecb();    

    }
    qDebug()<<"Running Thread.";
    sleep(6);

  } 
}

void MyJavaScriptOperations::JS_ADDED()
{
  qDebug()<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
  view->page()->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("myoperations", this); 
}

void MyJavaScriptOperations::loadFinished(bool oper)
{
  qDebug()<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<< oper;
  slot_installed = true;

 // firecb();

}

void MyJavaScriptOperations::firecb()
{
  qDebug()<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
  view->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("JavaScript_function()");
}

MyJavaScriptOperations::MyJavaScriptOperations()
{
    qDebug()<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    view = new QWebView();
    view->resize(400, 500);
    connect(view->page()->mainFrame(), SIGNAL(javaScriptWindowObjectCleared()), this, SLOT(JS_ADDED()));
    connect(view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), this, SLOT(loadFinished(bool)));
    view->load(QUrl("./index.html"));
    view->show();

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyJavaScriptOperations *jvs = new MyJavaScriptOperations;
    DemoThread *thread = new DemoThread(jvs);
    jvs->moveToThread(thread);
    thread->start();
    return a.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

This is the crash-error I get -

```
./QT_DEMO 
MyJavaScriptOperations::MyJavaScriptOperations() 
loaded the Generic plugin 
The code received is  156 
Running Thread. 
The code received is  166 
void MyJavaScriptOperations::firecb() 
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
```

Comment: You are doing something really dangerous. You are doing GUI stuff from a non-gui thread. Your `view` object is living in the GUI thread, as it should, but you're accessing its functions from a different thread, and those are not thread-safe functions. You also have no event loop running in your thread, so your slots will never be called through signals. And even if you did have an event loop running, your `while(1)` loop would block it.

Comment: The read() is making it event loop.

Comment: Is `read()` calling `QThread::exec()`?

Comment: My understanding of event loop is something that will wait for the event to occur, it will be blocked until any event occurs. Thus, I am using read(), that will block the thread until the read retrieves any thing. I have got a fix to the crash. Please see my solution. Please tell me, if there is a design problem. Btw, my character driver is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133981/how-to-gracefully-disable-the-interrupt-line-without-a-kernel-crash. The functionality works, but problem is when I remove the character driver. My system crashes.

Comment: And event loop must be entered somewhere. It doesn't do it magically by itself. When you call `QApplication::exec`, that enters the event loop. When you call `QThread::exec` that enters the event loop. If you want to use slots in your thread you must tell your thread to enter the event loop.

Comment: If I were you i'd ditch the `QThread` subclass. Just subclass `QObject` and call `QObject::moveToThread` like you are doing now. Do your threading there. And remove your `QWebView` from your class that you will move to a different thread. Put it in some class that will stay on the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few articles on internet how to make multithreaded applications in Qt. Best explanation can be found here:

http://blog.debao.me/2013/08/how-to-use-qthread-in-the-right-way-part-1/

You could read also other articles:

https://www.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong

http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/

Comment: I would actually recommend to **only** read the other articles as they clearly outline why the 'best explanation' (i.e. the first link to debao.me) is actually wrong... (Note that https://qt-project.org/wiki/QThreads_general_usage is copy-pasted from Maya Posch's blog...)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got a solution for my problem. Please tell me, am I complicating the solution.
I am using signal and slot. The thread will emit the signal and the slot of other class will emit the callback to the Qtwebkit - the javascript function. IS it right?
Because, I have suggestion using event loop - exec().

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QWebFrame>
#include <QWebPage>
#include <QWebView>
#include <QThread>

/** for reading my driver **/
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


class DemoThread;

class MyJavaScriptOperations : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

 public:

  QWebView *view;
  DemoThread *m_pDemoThread;
  MyJavaScriptOperations();
  void firecb();
  bool slot_installed;

signals:
 void  alert_script_signal();

public slots:
  void JsAdded();
  void alertReceived();
  void loadFinished(bool);

private:

};

 class DemoThread : public QThread
 {

Q_OBJECT

 private:

 MyJavaScriptOperations *m_pJavascriptOp;

 public:

    DemoThread( MyJavaScriptOperations *pJavascriptOp);

 protected:
        void run();

 signals:
        void  alertSendSignal();
};


 DemoThread::DemoThread(MyJavaScriptOperations *pJavascriptOp):m_pJavascriptOp(pJavascriptOp)
{
  connect(this, SIGNAL(alertSendSignal()), m_pJavascriptOp, SLOT(alertReceived()));

}

void DemoThread:: run()
{
  int filedesc = open("/dev/pSeudoDrv", O_RDONLY);

  if(filedesc < 0)
      {
          qDebug()<<"Couldn't open Driver.";
      }

  unsigned char buff;

  while(1)
  {
    if( 1 != read(filedesc,&buff, 1))
    {
        qDebug()<<"Read Invalid Data";
    }

    qDebug()<<"The code received is "<< buff;

    /** In my laptop, the 166 means the character 'l' **/
    if ( (m_pJavascriptOp->slot_installed == true)  && (buff == 166))
    {
        emit alertSendSignal();
    }
    qDebug()<<"Running Thread.";

  }
}

void MyJavaScriptOperations::JsAdded()
{
  qDebug()<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
  view->page()->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("myoperations", this);
}

void MyJavaScriptOperations::loadFinished(bool oper)
{
  qDebug()<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<< oper;
  slot_installed = true;
}

void MyJavaScriptOperations::alertReceived()
{
    qDebug()<<"Sending Firecallback now";
    firecb();
}

void MyJavaScriptOperations::firecb()
{
  qDebug()<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
  view->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("JavaScript_function()");
}

MyJavaScriptOperations::MyJavaScriptOperations()
{
    qDebug()<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    view = new QWebView();
    view->resize(400, 500);
    connect(view->page()->mainFrame(), SIGNAL(javaScriptWindowObjectCleared()), this, SLOT(JsAdded()));
    connect(view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), this, SLOT(loadFinished(bool)));
    view->load(QUrl("./index.html"));
    view->show();

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyJavaScriptOperations *jvs = new MyJavaScriptOperations;
    DemoThread *thread = new DemoThread(jvs);
    thread->start();
    return a.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: The last code looks better. QThread it often used to protect the GUI from IO blocking operation. But it would be better to use Qt also for IO operations, see QIODevice, QFile, QDataStream, QTextStream classes. Some of the QIODevice derived classes (QTcpSocket) are event driven so there is no need to use QThread.